# Tracking what all items of a list are currently visible on the screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view

Suppose I have a recyclerview with 10 items. Out of these 10, 0 - 4 are visible in one go. On scrolling down, 0th element goes away from the screen and 5th one enters. I want to track these events - where I get to know that elements 0 - 4 are visible and then on scrolling, 1-5 are.

Is there anyway to achieve this? I want to keep track of how long a user is spending time on a particular items of the recyclerview.

Comment: are you using LinearLayoutManager?

Comment: this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113642/how-to-get-top-item-of-recyclerview-on-scroll

Comment: @lelloman Yes! But I would prefer a method that is applicable on all kinds of layouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set **addOnScrollListener** on RecyclerView and get first and last visible rows

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            int firstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            // Now you can easily get all rows b/w first and last item
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This works but be aware that if the recyclerview is inside a nested scrollview, it'll return the first and the last position no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid /  linear layout methods (`findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`, `findLastVisibleItemPosition()`, `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`, `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`) to track the visible and completely visible item

and if you want to track `is item visible on screen` for some `threshold` means `user spent enough time to view the content` then you can refer to the following blog.

a very nice blog which demonstrates the use of `scroll callbacks of LayoutManager` and `RxJava Subscribers` to track item visibility meets the threshold
https://proandroiddev.com/detecting-list-items-perceived-by-user-8f164dfb1d05